# How to change a color when a number increases?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making an app which displays a value from 1 to 50, and I want to change the colours like a rainbow, so if the value is 1, the color = blue, and if the value = 50, the color is red.

I already tried this, only this does't change the color in rainbow way:

```py
    for i in range(value):
        x += 40
        color = (x,255,250-x)
```

Is there any way how this can be done?

Comment: Lerp between two different colours

Comment: RGB stand for Red, Green, Blue. Your color (R,G,B) should reflect all options you want. Currently you are only editing the 'R' component of the color

Comment: @NemoMeMeliorEst tnx, I already knew that tho, only can you help me with changing in rainbow way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a question about how color works. You notice it's a 3-tuple:

```
color = (red, green, blue)
```

Computer colors generally work by [additive color mixing](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/addcol.html). If you have no color at all, you get black. If you have the maximum value for red, green, and blue, you get white. If you wanted to go from red to blue through purple, you'd do something like this:

```
color = (255-x, 0, x)
```

---

What you want instead, if you want to transition *across a rainbow* from red through yellow, orange, green, blue, violet, and red again, is not RGB color space, but HSV (Hue, Saturation, Value). I'll assume whatever you're using to output the color requires it be in RGB, but even then, [Python provides a module for converting between the two](https://docs.python.org/3/library/colorsys.html):

```
import colorsys
...
color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb((x / 255), 1, 1)
```

Note that the functions in `colorsys` only take values between 0 and 1, so if you want them in terms of 255 you'll have to multiply the vector by 255 after you get it:

```
color = (255 * c for c in colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(x/255, 1, 1))
```